# Why two datetime.time cannot be substracted?

Tags: python

For satisfying my curiosity, is there any reason why two datetime.time values cannot be direclty subtracted?

```
seconds = (datetime.combine(date.today(), end_time) - datetime.combine(date.today(), start_time)).total_seconds()
```

works, but

```
seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
```

does not.  Is there any particular reason?

thank you.

Comment: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- note that our focus is on specific, practical problems you actually face. "How do I work around this?" is a practical problem for which a solution can be demonstrably correct or demonstrably wrong; "why do I need to work around this?" is curiosity (and can often be a call for speculation/opinions/rants/etc).

Comment: Without a date, how is it supposed to know what tie difference is? The times could have been taken from different days.

Comment: @Barmar I suppose you could just make the assumption that the times are on the same day, which it seems `datetime.time` must do to implement the comparison operators (which it does!).

Comment: I mean, they _could_ have implemented time subtraction with the assumption that both times are on the same date. As for why they didn't, that goes to Charles' link.

Comment: Maybe because `datetime.time` is always naive about of daylight savings times and leap seconds.